# C read binary stdin

Tags: c, binary, stdin

I'm trying to build an instruction pipeline simulator and I'm having a lot of trouble getting started. What I need to do is read binary from stdin, and then store it in memory somehow while I manipulate the data. I need to read in chunks of exactly 32 bits one after the other.

How do I read in chunks of exactly 32 bits at a time? Secondly, how do I store it for manipulation later?

Here's what I've got so far, but examining the binary chunks I read further, it just doesn't look right, I don't think I'm reading exactly 32 bits like I need.

```
char buffer[4] = { 0 }; // initialize to 0
unsigned long c = 0;
int bytesize = 4; // read in 32 bits
while (fgets(buffer, bytesize, stdin)) {
  memcpy(&c, buffer, bytesize); // copy the data to a more usable structure for bit manipulation later
  // more stuff
  buffer[0] = 0; buffer[1] = 0; buffer[2] = 0; buffer[3] = 0; // set to zero before next loop
}
fclose(stdin);
```

How do I read in 32 bits at a time (they are all 1/0, no newlines etc), and what do I store it in, is `char[]` okay?

EDIT: I'm able to read the binary in but none of the answers produce the bits in the correct order — they are all mangled up, I suspect endianness and problems reading and moving 8 bits around ( 1 char) at a time — this needs to work on Windows and C ... ?

Comment: actually you can just read either byte by byte or 4 bytes per call, because you need to store the data to a buffer. once got buffer stores whatever length of data, you could process the buffer 4 byte by 4 byte. since stdin/stdout is though as streamy, so byte by byte is natural too. unlike socket I/O, normally you can ignore byte-order upon stdin etc, of course if you need , do byte-order convert yourself. because of no newline (e.g. '\n'), use read or fread would be better. please think it as a stream.

Comment: None of these solutions read in the binary in correct order! Help please, deadline approaching.

Comment: x86 platforms are little endian, you cant expect to have in _c_ the bits in the rigth order.

Comment: +1 yes I've often wondered about this ... what's the question again?

Comment: How to read in binary bits and then segment those bits into (perhaps oddly sized) chunks, bitmasks for example.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had it right the first time, except, I needed ntohl ... [C Endian Conversion : bit by bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614399/c-endian-conversion-bit-by-bit/1615275#1615275)

Answer (score 32):

What you need is [`freopen()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/freopen.html). From the manpage:

> If filename is a null pointer, the freopen() function shall attempt to change the mode of the stream to that specified by mode, as if the name of the file currently associated with the stream had been used. In this case, the file descriptor associated with the stream need not be closed if the call to freopen() succeeds. It is implementation-defined which changes of mode are permitted (if any), and under what circumstances.

Basically, the best you can really do is this:

```
freopen(NULL, "rb", stdin);
```

This will reopen `stdin` to be the same input stream, but in binary mode. In the normal mode, reading from `stdin` on Windows will convert `\r\n` (Windows newline) to the single character ASCII 10. Using the `"rb"` mode disables this conversion so that you can properly read in binary data.

`freopen()` returns a filehandle, but it's the previous value (before we put it in binary mode), so don't use it for anything. After that, use [`fread()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fread.html) as has been mentioned.

As to your concerns, however, you may not be reading in "32 bits" but if you use `fread()` you *will* be reading in 4 `char`s (which is the best you can do in C - `char` is guaranteed to be *at least* 8 bits but some historical and embedded platforms have 16 bit `char`s (some even have 18 or worse)). If you use `fgets()` you will *never* read in 4 bytes. You will read in at least 3 (depending on whether any of them are newlines), and the 4th byte will be `'\0'` because C strings are nul-terminated and `fgets()` nul-terminates what it reads (like a good function). Obviously, this is not what you want, so you should use `fread()`.

Comment: There's no need to even try to assign the return value of `freopen` to `stdin` - `freopen` either returns `NULL` or the previous value of `stdin` (it changes the pointed-to `FILE` but doesn't change the `FILE *` value itself)

Comment: Ah. I didn't realized it returned the old value. Edited to fix.

Comment: As always, Windows is different. It doesn't permit `NULL` for the `path` parameter. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7053024/779419) comment.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work on Windows, for the reason given by @schieferstapel: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk2h68td.aspx. -1.

Answer (score 22):

Consider using `SET_BINARY_MODE` macro and `setmode`:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
# include <io.h>
# include <fcntl.h>
# define SET_BINARY_MODE(handle) setmode(handle, O_BINARY)
#else
# define SET_BINARY_MODE(handle) ((void)0)
#endif
```

More details about `SET_BINARY_MODE` macro here: "[Handling binary files via standard I/O](https://web.archive.org/web/20090907131154/http://www.cs.toronto.edu:80/~ramona/cosmin/TA/prog/sysconf/)"

More details about `setmode` here: ["_setmode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa298581%28VS.60%29.aspx)"

Comment: thanks for your mentioning _setmode. This it was actually worked for me (I was trying to open stdout for binary).

Comment: `# define SET_BINARY_MODE(handle) ((void)0)` doesn't work for me. I'm using an Atmega 128A1 and it seems to be impossible to set `stdout` into binary mode. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I had to piece the answer together from the various comments from the kind people above, so here is a fully-working sample that works - only for Windows, but you can probably translate the windows-specific stuff to your platform.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    char rbuf[4096];
    char *deffile = "c:\\temp\\outvideo.bin";
    size_t r;
    char *outfilename = deffile;
    FILE *newin;

    freopen(NULL, "rb", stdin);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);

    FILE *f = fopen(outfilename, "w+b");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("unable to open %s\n", outfilename);
        exit(1);
    }

    for (;; )
    {
        r = fread(rbuf, 1, sizeof(rbuf), stdin);
        if (r > 0)
        {
            size_t w;
            for (size_t nleft = r; nleft > 0; )
            {
                w = fwrite(rbuf, 1, nleft, f);
                if (w == 0)
                {
                    printf("error: unable to write %d bytes to %s\n", nleft, outfilename);
                    exit(1);
                }
                nleft -= w;
                fflush(f);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Sleep(10); // wait for more input, but not in a tight loop
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, this [Microsoft _setmode example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=vs-2019) specifically shows how to change stdin to binary mode:

```
// crt_setmode.c
// This program uses _setmode to change
// stdin from text mode to binary mode.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

int main( void )
{
   int result;

   // Set "stdin" to have binary mode:
   result = _setmode( _fileno( stdin ), _O_BINARY );
   if( result == -1 )
      perror( "Cannot set mode" );
   else
      printf( "'stdin' successfully changed to binary mode\n" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fgets() is all wrong here. It's aimed at human-readable ASCII text terminated by end-of-line characters, not binary data, and won't get you what you need.

I recently did exactly what you want using the [read()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) call. Unless your program has explicitly closed stdin, for the first argument (the file descriptor), you can use a constant value of 0 for stdin. Or, if you're on a POSIX system (Linux, Mac OS X, or some other modern variant of Unix), you can use STDIN_FILENO.

Comment: This won't work for non-POSIX systems, of course, which defeats the purpose, because on POSIX systems there is no difference between binary reading and text reading for filehandles.

Answer (score -1):

[fread()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/) suits best for reading binary data.

Yes, char array is OK, if you are planning to process them bytewise.

Comment: This is not the answer. `stdin` is a buffered input stream, and `fread()` will read buffered data, and on Windows it will be reading in text mode and convert `\r\n` to a single character, which will be bad for binary data.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what OS you are running, but you typically cannot "open stdin in binary".  You can try things like

```
int fd = fdreopen (fileno (stdin), outfname, O_RDONLY | OPEN_O_BINARY);
```

to try to force it.  Then use

```
uint32_t opcode;
read(fd, &opcode, sizeof (opcode));
```

But I have no actually tried it myself.  :)

Comment: You don't have to do the fdreopen(). stdin is always open - see my answer.

Comment: WTF??  I know its open, that's the only kind of file you can *FEED* into fdreopen.  But it has the wrong *MODE*.  stdin is opened as a *TEXT* file.  The guy wants to read raw binary data, and text isn't going to cut it.