# Fgets Ignored after its run one time in C Programming?

Tags: c, fgets

So this is the code, its pretty simple, but why isn't the `fgets` prompted again after the first loop? and age is. (And weirdly it works with `scanf("%s",&name_temp)` but I need to grab other characters too like áéíóúÇ, spaces, so it would be better with `fgets`)

```
 int menu_option = 0;
 char name_temp[80] = "";
 int age_temp = 0;

 while(menu_option != 9){

     //strcpy(name_temp,"");

     printf("Type your name\n");
     fgets(name_temp, 80, stdin);

     printf("\nType your age\n");
     scanf("%d", &age_temp);

 }
```

---

***(moved from the deleted answer)***

Guys thanks for your answers, but I don't think you guys understood my question, test this code that I sent, and you will see that instead of appearing the thing in the Terminal for you to type, it is just ignored after the first while loop.

What I wanted is that after the first loop (while) it came back and asked again the name of the person and the person using the program would have to type again. but instead of that, after the first time of the loop, it just doesn't ask for you to type anything, the fgets is completely ignored.

please try the code and say what can I do.

I tried the freopen thing and did not work.

Comment: You don't need to put [VERY SIMPLE QUESTION] after your question.

Comment: @user: Note that markdown makes a formatting distinction between quotations (using `> `) and code blocks (using four spaces), and note that programmers consider case to be part of the spelling of identifiers, so "Fgets" is not the same as "fgets".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should open `stdin` in binary mode. Use `freopen(NULL, "rb", stdin)` to do this.

See [C read binary stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598985/c-read-binary-stdin) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

When I ran it, it did indeed print out "Type your name" each time through the loop, but did not wait for input, because it was getting the '\n' which the call to scanf left on the input stream.  This is a common problem; one solution is to insert getchar(); at the bottom of the loop, to eat that newline.

Answer (score 2):

`fgets` read a line, that is, it read `stdin` until `\n` character is reached.

`scanf` left the `\n` character into `stdin`.

Then, `fgets` read an empty line.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP asking about.

Comment: @MihranHovsepyan Seems to me that this is exactly what his problem is

Answer (score 0):

I hope I answer your question.

What I found to work is to add this line in the loop.

```
fflush(stdin);
```

more especially after

```
scanf("%d", &age_temp);
```

Comment: This is bad advice. You shouldn't fluxh input streams.