# Problems using fread() on stdin under win32

Tags: c, windows, pipe, stdio

I'm trying to parse data from stdin in binary mode under Win32.
The first thing my code does is to check for a 4byte header at the beginning:

```
int riff_header;
fread(&riff_header, sizeof(riff_header), 1, ifp);
//  'RIFF' = little-endian
if (riff_header != 0x46464952) {
    fprintf(stderr, "wav2msu: Incorrect header: Invalid format or endianness\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "         Value was: 0x%x\n", riff_header);
    return -1;
}
```

`stdin` has been switched to binary mode before reading from it:

```
if (*argv[argc-1] == '-') {
    fprintf(stderr, "Reading from stdin.\n");
    infile = stdin;
    // We need to switch stdin to binary mode, or else we run
    // into problems under Windows
    freopen(NULL, "rb", stdin);
}
```

This code works fine under Linux, however on Win32 (specifically Windows XP), the `fread` only seems to read a single byte and thus cause the evaluation to fail.
Example:

```
> ffmeg.exe -i ..\test.mp3 -f wav pipe:1 2> nul |..\foo.exe -o test.bin -
Reading from stdin.
foo: Incorrect header: Invalid format or endianness
     Value was: 0x4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you don't do the `freopen`?

Comment: The header checks fine, but I get nonsensical results with other checks I run later, due to windows handling newlines differently :-/

Comment: Ok.  I just wanted to double-check that this problem is specific to reopened stdin, not just Windows in general.

Comment: Would it be an option to filter the input and translate the \r\n sequences to \n?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/freopen.html I have found the following:

> If filename is a null pointer, the freopen() function shall attempt to
>   change the mode of the stream to that specified by mode, as if the
>   name of the file currently associated with the stream had been used.
>   In this case, the file descriptor associated with the stream need not
>   be closed if the call to freopen() succeeds. It is
>   implementation-defined which changes of mode are permitted (if any),
>   and under what circumstances.

Maybe you should check if the change of mode (from text to binary) is allowed by the compiler and libraries you are using. Which compiler are you using?

**Update / summary**

Using MinGW you can call setmode() to switch the mode of the stdin stream.
You should set the mode to _O_BINARY, which is defined in fcntl.h.
For more information see e.g. [http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/compile.html](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/compile.html#Text_files_and_binary_files)

Comment: I'm using GCC 4.5.2 under MinGW.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk2h68td%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), it's not permitted to pass `NULL` for the `path` parameter of `freopen`, so the call to `freopen` is almost certainly failing; have you checked the return value and the value of `errno`?  C89 does not specify the behavior of `freopen` when `path` is `NULL`; C99 does, but the Microsoft C runtime is not (and does not claim to be) C99-compliant.

If you really need to read binary info from `stdin`, you might have to use platform-specific code and read the raw binary data directly with [`ReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the file [`GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Or `setmode(fileno(stdin), O_BINARY);` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8\(v=vs.80\).aspx)

Comment: @user786653: Ah, good call, I was not aware of that function.  You should add that as an answer.

Comment: setmode() should also work with MinGW. See http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/compile.html, section "Text files and binary files".

Comment: @user786653: When I try that, the compiler complains that it cannot find the declaration of O_BINARY. I included `io.h`, though :-/

Comment: Under MinGW it should be #include <fcntl.h>, and the constant is _O_BINARY (see the link above).

Comment: @Giorgio, thanks for this link, it mentioned `fcntl.h` and including that did the trick. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it :-)

Comment: Thanks. I could add it to my answer, but setmode() was user786653's suggestion. I will wait in case he wants to add it as an answer. It's his call. If he doesn't, I will add it to my answer.