# Reading from standard in using ios::binary

Tags: c++, stream, binary, stdin, cin

I'm trying to read from standard input and distinguish each character from one another by its decimal value.  From what I understand, a Line Feed (10) and a Carriage Return (13) will be interpreted as the same character.  I want to distinguish between the two.  I know if I was reading from a file I could open it using the ios::binary parameter.  But what about if I am reading from standard input?

Comment: If you know your platform, you could try to reopen `stdin` using an `ifstream` (the point I can't do it in a portable way, `/dev/stdin` should work for -ixes), then use `rdbuf` to hook that into `std::cin`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587595/read-binary-data-from-stdcin

Comment: Also see the discussion of using [`std::freopen`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39758021/608639) (but it looks kind of hacky). It would be nice if someone provided a canonical answer with examples for BSDs, Linux, OS X, Solaris and Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read from std::cin by using get. This method is specially designed for reading unformatted data ([see doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/))

Comment: I think the problem is, `std::cin` is opened in text mode. There may be some unwanted translations due to text mode.