# ifstream.eof() - end of file is reached before the real end

Tags: c++, ifstream, fread

I have a roughly 11.1G binary file where stores a series of the depth frames from the Kinect. There are 19437 frames in this file. To read one frame per time, I use ***ifstream*** in ***fstream*** but it reaches ***eof*** before the real end of the file. (I only got the first 20 frames, and the function stops because of the ***eof*** flag)

However, all frames can be read by using ***fread*** in ***stdio*** instead.

Can anyone explain this situation? Thank you for precious time on my question.

Here are my two functions:

```
// ifstream.read() - Does Not Work: the loop will stop after 20th frame because of the eof flag
ifstream depthStream("fileName.dat");
if(depthStream.is_open())
{
  while(!depthStream.eof())
  {
    char* buffer = new char[640*480*2];
    depthStream.read(buffer, 640*480*2);

    // Store the buffer data in OpenCV Mat

    delete[] buffer;
  }
}

// fread() - Work: Get 19437 frames successfully
FILE* depthStream
depthStream = fopen("fileName.dat", "rb");
if(depthStream != NULL)
{
  while(!feof(depthStream))
  {
    char* buffer = new char[640*480*2];
    fread(buffer, 1, 640*480*2, depthStream);

    // Store the buffer data in OpenCV Mat

    delete[] buffer;
}
```

Again, thank you for precious time on my question

Comment: you open the C stream in binary mode, why didn't you open the C++ stream in binary mode?  `ifstream depthStream("fileName.dat", std::ios_base::bin);`  (Also, deleting and reaquiring your buffer each iteration seems a little silly doesn't it?  And use `std::vector` for the buffer.)

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong. In addition, you probably want to use something like `std::vector<char> buffer(size);` instead of `buffer = new char[size];`

Comment: This: `while(!depthStream.eof()` is always wrong.  Other conditions can cause a read to fail aside from end of file.

Comment: Also see [Reading from text file until EOF repeats last line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21647/608639), [How does ifstream's eof() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4533063/608639) and all the related posts.

Answer (score 20):

You need to open the stream in binary mode, otherwise it will stop at the first byte it sees with a value of 26.

```
ifstream depthStream("fileName.dat", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
```

As for why 26 is special, it's the code for Ctrl-Z which was a convention used to mark the end of a text file. The history behind this was recorded in Raymond Chen's blog post [Why do text files end in Ctrl+Z?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040316-00/?p=40233).

Comment: wait, stop at the first byte with a 26?  I've never heard of such a thing.  I thought text mode merely translated `\r\n` into `\n` on windows, and did nothing on linux/mac. [my Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%2B%2B%20stream%2026) doesn't immediately find any connection between streams and "26"...

Comment: @MooingDuck, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008907/c-cin-fails-when-reading-more-than-127-ascii-values

Comment: @MooingDuck - this is a Microsoft thing; ctrl-Z in a text file is treated as end of file in their C library.

Comment: Just spent 2 days trying to figure out what the hell was happening here... Thank you Stack Overflow!

Comment: Upvoted because I've been stuck on this problem for the past 3 hours. Never ever heard of 26 being so special. Learned something very interesting today