# Windows IStream interface on std::istream

Tags: c++, windows, com, istream

Within C++ on Windows, is there any easy way to create a (COM) `IStream` interface to an existing `std::stream` object?

An example would be to read an image with `IWICStream::InitializeFromIStream()` from `std::cin`.

Comment: IStream is an interface, it is up to you to provide the implementation.  You'd generally only have to implement Read and Seek, return E_NOTIMPL for the rest.  Don't try to read binary data from a text stream like std::cin.

Comment: @HansPassant it's OK to read binary data from `cin` if you set it up properly first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11259588/5987. No reason that piping should be crippled on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard implementation for that.  You need to write your class (or find a third-party one) that implements the `IStream` interface and internally delegates to an `std::stream` as needed.  However, you are likely to have trouble implementing `IStream::Stat()`, which is commonly used to retrieve a stream's data size.  In the case of `std::cin`, you would not know how much data is being provided.