# Reading PNG file from cin

Tags: c++, png

I was about to read a PNG file from stdin using the following code:

```
std::string input;
char ch;
std::cin >> std::noskipws;
while (!std::cin.eof())
{
    std::cin.get(ch);
    input += ch;
}
```

However, I could only get 5 bytes since PNG header contains a Ctrl-Z and stops reading.

What should I do to read the whole file?

Answer (score 2):

std::cin is opened in text mode and you need to read binary data.

[Have a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587595/read-binary-data-from-stdcin)

Comment: If the answers are so similar, why did you answer instead of you tagging it as a duplicate? This answer is basically a comment.