# Unknown cin properties

Tags: c++, cin, istream

Try as I might, I cannot find any information on what `cin.binary` is for.

similar ones, thinking bases, dec, hex, octal only seem to appear when used with cout - e.g.,

`cout << std::hex << n;`.

However `cout << std::binary << n;` isn't valid

Entering `cin.` produces this intellisense popup

[image: intellisense popup for <code>cin.</code>]

I'm left assuming that these are some sort of flags. Sure would be nice to know for sure though.

Comment: http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode

Comment: Did you try [looking at the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode)?

Comment: IntelliSense is not documentation.

Comment: you could have saved some typing if you simply searched those on web

Comment: Of course I did try looking on the web. "cin.binary" doesn't give any result that actually include that exact string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`binary` is a flag to tell the stream to be opened in binary mode (instead of textual mode).

You can find documentation on these flags here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode

You might also search on this site for other flags and functions of `std::basic_istream`(e.g. `std::cin`):
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [std::ios_base::openmode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode)

binary is used to open a istream in binary mode (as opposed to text mode).

std::cin is not open in binary mode, please read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587595/read-binary-data-from-stdcin) for more details.