# What is the equivalent of char(0) or '\0' for wchar_t?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::wcout.imbue(std::locale("zh_CN.UTF-8"));

    std::wcout << wchar_t(0) << L"哈哈" << std::endl;
    std::cout << char(0) << "haha" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---------------" << std::endl;

    std::wcout.clear();
    std::wcout << L"哈哈" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "haha" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---------------" << std::endl;

    std::wcout << L'\0' << L"哈哈" << std::endl;
    std::cout << '\0' << "haha" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---------------" << std::endl;

    std::wcout.clear();
    std::wcout << L"哈哈" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "haha" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The `wchar_t(0)` and `L'\0'` seem to different from `char(0)` and `'\0'` and cause the `ostream` to have bad state.

It took me some time to figure out the missing output is not caused by the locale setting but the `wchar_t` since my original program has somewhere output a `wchar_t(0)` or `'\0'`.

My question is how are they different from the `char` version? And how to correctly use an empty `wchar_t`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe it's `L'\0'`.

Comment: Text streams do not support outputting a null character, so you should not try this in the first place

Comment: @M.M Thanks for your information. I come from Python and don't know about this in C++. Is there any reference to this?

Comment: You can try using the `put` function to write a single character, no formatting.  But in general for binary data you should not be using C++ streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The null wide character can be written as `wchar_t(0)` or `L'\0'`.

The different behaviour you observe is because `cout` and `wcout` are *text streams*.  According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c#Binary_and_text_modes), you should only use printable characters, `\t` and `\n` on a text stream.  Sending a null character to the text stream may have unexpected results.

If you want to use `cout` as a binary stream in Windows there are some hacks you can do , [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587595/read-binary-data-from-stdcin/11259588) for ideas.

I am not sure whether those hacks would work for `wcout`; but from past experience, the status of `wcout` support in compilers is dubious and I have found it more reliable to just use `stdout` and do any required translation using facets or explicit functions etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm implementing a `trie` tree and giving an empty wchar_t for the default root node. I can get the correct output of the whole tree recursively unless the root is not an empty wchar_t. I think I should change this default behavior now.