# Reading user input after reading a file from stdin

Tags: c++, c

I have a program that I start from a command line with a file pushed to `stdin`:

`main.exe < file.bin`

I read all the contents from the file like so:

```
freopen(NULL, "rb", stdin);    // it's a binary file
long* buffer = new long[16000];
while ( fread(buffer, sizeof(long), 16000, stdin) == 16000);
```

After all numbers are read, I would like the user to confirm continuation in the program by pressing any key but at that point `stdin` probably contains `EOF` and the program skips the confirmation from the user.

```
printf("Press any key to continue");
getchar();    // user doesn't get a chance to press anything, program flows right through
```

Here's the whole program if you want to reproduce it. But to reproduce you have to push a file to stdin before execution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    freopen(NULL, "rb", stdin);
    long* buffer = new long[16000];
    while ( fread(buffer, sizeof(long), 16000, stdin) == 16000);
    printf("Press any key to continue");
    getchar();
    delete[] buffer;
    return 0;
}
```

The question is how to make the `getchar()` call take an character from the user's keyboard and not the file that was already read.

The program runs as C++17 but uses a lot of C style code. If you know a way how to do this with C++ streams feel free to post that as well. I use Windows 10 but I would also like to see some portable code.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to hammer a square peg into a round hole. Why not just provide the input filename as a command line argument (`main.exe file.bin`) and keep `stdin` free for user input when you need it?

Comment: Open the file with `fopen("File.bin", "rb")` Also the code will ignore the early part if it has more than 16000 elements. Better to capture the return value from `fread`.

Comment: If it's running as C++17, `<filesystem>` is worth learning.

Comment: I know that would work, but in my environment it's currently not possible. I can only do `<` operation.

Comment: @sanitizedUser what makes impossible to use `fopen` or `<filesystem>` in your environment ?

Comment: @NicolasDusart I send a solution code to a server that uses the `<` operation and I cannot change that. Anyway, this was just a test for me to test reading of the file. On the server there is no user that can press keyboard obviously.

Comment: What's the point of the final `getchar()` anyway. Is it for avoiding Windows to close the terminal window ? It is already started from terminal to pass file as stdin, just let it close the program, the terminal will be kept open.

Comment: @NicolasDusart The test version is running under VS2019 and I don't want to set breakpoint at the last line because sometimes I carry the project around between different IDEs.

Comment: @Adler If I wanted to provide more detail I would have answered instead of commented. But, I mean, `<filesystem>` is the C++17 way of working with files.

Comment: @sweenish, how is that supposed to be helpful, given the question at hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a file `file.bin` as a stdin via `main.exe < file.bin`, you cannot simultaneously use console as a stdin using standard C or C++ libraries. Maybe you could try it with WinAPI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput
And using std::cin to read binary data is unfortulately not possible: [Read binary data from std::cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587595/read-binary-data-from-stdcin)