# C++ Reading characters from stdin works on linux but not on windows

Tags: c++, stdin, eof, getchar

I am experimenting with this open source LZW compression code off github.  The code compresses my binary file correctly, but when trying to decompress it, the code calls `getchar` and reaches `EOF` within 20 characters from a 50,000+ character file.

Github Repository:

```
https://github.com/geoffreylitt/lzw
```

I looked through the decode function to see what was wrong.  Eventually I trimmed the code down to only this:

```
void decode()
{
    int c = 0;
    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%i\n", c);
    }
}
```

This is the makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-O3 -g3 --std=c99 -Wall

all: encode decode

encode: main.c hasharray.c encode.c decode.c bitio.c stack.c globals.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o ../bin/encode $^

decode: encode
    ln -f ../bin/encode ../bin/decode
```

And this is how I was executing the script:

```
./decode <encoded.bin> decoded.bin
```

I think it has something to do with how stdin handles the file input.  But I don't have much of an understanding of how it handles an input stream from `<encoded.bin>`.

On Ubuntu 16.04 near fresh install, it works perfectly with the same code, same files, and same command.  I would really like to know why or how they handle this differently so later down the road if my code has the same issue I might realize why.

`Thanks!`

Comment: What compiler do you use for windows ?

Comment: I'd guess that `stdin` in Windows is open in text mode and you're hitting a ctrl-z in the input which is `EOF`. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942518/c-reading-from-stdin-stops-at-0x1a-character