# Simple encryption/decryption algorithm causing EOF

Tags: c, encryption, stdio

I was playing with very simple encryption/decryption algorithm like this;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFESIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int keylen = 0;
    char *key = argv[1];
    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t buffersize = 0;
    size_t nbytes = 0;
    size_t nread;
    int i = 0;
    while(*key++ != 0) keylen++;
    key = argv[1];

    do {
        buffersize+=BUFFESIZE;
        buffer = realloc(buffer, buffersize);
        nread = fread(buffer+nbytes, 1, BUFFESIZE, stdin);
        nbytes+=nread;
    } while (nread > 0);

    for(i=0; i<nbytes; i++) {
        putchar(buffer[i] ^ key[i % keylen]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Encyption key is the first command-line argument to the program. I expect that this should get me originial file when encrypted/decrypted with same key. However, I sometimes get only small amount of the file back if I encrypt/decrypt it. My guess is that algorithm adds EOF control character in the middle of file.

How can I get around this problem?

I compiled this using MinGW gcc 4.8.1 on windows XP.  If you're interested, you can find a sample input file demonstrating the problem in [the edit history of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28781430/2).

Comment: Your code works fine for me (on Linux / GCC). What OS and compiler are you using? Also, it would help if you could paste in a short example of a file and a key that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: In any case, you might want to try [setting stdin and stdout to binary mode.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598985/c-read-binary-stdin)

Comment: I'm guessing that the *ciphertext* has a `00` valued byte in it and that the rest isn't read.

Comment: @Maarten: Actually, nulls are not a problem for `fread()`. Apparently, however, on WIndows in text mode, the Ctrl-Z character (0x1A) is.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Ugh, that's another entry in my Windows weirdness table inside my head. Growing and growing, hopefully I can put it into `{any folder at all}/NUL` someday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your code works for me on Linux (compiled with GCC 4.8.2), even using your sample input and key.  This suggests that the issue is specific to Windows — most likely, that it's caused by stdin and stdout being in [text mode](http://c-faq.com/stdio/textvsbinary.html) by default.  (On Linux and other Unix-ish systems, there's usually no difference between text mode and binary mode, so such issues do not show up there.)

To fix it, you will need to [set stdin and stdout to binary mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598985/c-read-binary-stdin).  The [standard way of doing this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/freopen.html), as of [C99](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), would be:

```c
freopen(NULL, "rb", stdin);
freopen(NULL, "wb", stdout);
```

but alas, according to the answers in the thread I linked to above, the Windows C library [does not support this C99 feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk2h68td.aspx), so you'll need to fall back on the non-standard [`_setmode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8.aspx) instead:

```c
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);
```

If you want to remain portable, you could always use some conditional code, e.g. like this (warning: not actually tested on Windows!):

```c
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
  #define binmode(fh, w) freopen(NULL, ((w) ? "wb" : "rb"), (fh)) /* C99 */
#elif _MSC_VER >= 1200
  #include <io.h>
  #include <fcntl.h>
  #define binmode(fh, w) _setmode(_fileno(fh), _O_BINARY) /* MSVC 6.0+ */
#elif defined(__unix__) || (defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__))
  #define binmode(fh, w) /* Unix-ish, just do nothing */
#else
  #error Not sure how to define binmode() on this platform
#endif

binmode(stdin, 0);
binmode(stdout, 1);
```

Or, of course, you could just sidestep the whole issue by opening your own input and output files (in binary mode) instead of using `stdin` and `stdout`.

Comment: I opened my own input and output files. I thought it was a simpler solution. And it works too.