# How i can read binary files using stdin and < operator

Tags: command-line-interface, console-application, mingw

I write WINDOWS CLI APP using mingw. I need to read stream  that contain mixed raw binary data (0x00) and chars (0x30 for exaple) from console. I try to use main.exe < test.bin    (redirect file stream to stdin)

```
 ch=getchar();
or ch=getch();
```

But this functions does not read  data correctly. Where is my mistake?
This is file content: Raw data and decoded text
[image: File content]

I try to trace app using gdb but app does not stop at  ch=getchar(). I suppouse the problem is in terminal mode but i have no idea how to resolve it. If i send simple text file with hex values debug work fine.

Comment: What's your raw data and what is the decoded data?
If your data is binary you need to read the input in binary mode to avoid line break conversions.

Comment: In the left part raw binary data 0x01 0x30 0x31 etc..What is the binary mode? This is special console terminal mode? How I can switch to it? I suppose when I use getch() instead of getchar() this function read key codes directly from keyboard not from stdin.

Comment: Some suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598985/c-read-binary-stdin