# Passing bytes from Python to a C++ Subprocess via stdin fails on Windows

Tags: python, c++, windows, subprocess, pipe

I have a python program that runs iterations of a loop. During the loop there is a part of the code that can run in parallel, to do this I decided to use a C++ program that I have pre-compiled and I call as a subprocess. This program needs an input that is about 1K bytes long and will return a few bytes as an answer.

In the C++ program I have the following method to read the input bytes from stdin:

```
#include <iostream>
#define VAR_NUM 1000         // number of bytes to read
using namespace std;

void read_vars(int* vars){
    char buf;
    int chk;

    for(int i=0; i<VAR_NUM; i++){
        chk = fread(&buf, sizeof(char), 1, stdin);
        std::cout << (int)(unsigned char)buf << "(" << chk << ") ";
        vars[i] = (int)(unsigned char)buf;
        if(chk==0){
            if(feof(stdin)) std::cout << "[EOF] ";
            if(ferror(stdin)) std::cout << "[ERROR] ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << endl;
    return;
}

int main(){
    int* vars = (int*) malloc(VAR_NUM*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0; i<VAR_NUM; i++) vars[i] = 0;
    read_vars(vars);
    return 0;
}
```

It reads bytes from stdin and places them in the pre-allocated vars array as integers. For now stdout is used for debugging, so every byte read is printed along with it's fread return value and the status of stdin in case of an error.

On the Python side I run the following code to invoke the compiled C++ program:

```
import os
import random
from subprocess import run, Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL, STDOUT

def run_cpp(vars):
    command = os.path.join('.', 'program')
    inp = bytes(vars)

    proc = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, text=False) # will have stdout=PIPE in final code
    print('python wrote:', proc.stdin.write(inp),'bytes\n')
    print('vars read by c++:')
    res, err = proc.communicate()

    print('\n'+'stderr:', err, '\n')
    print('stdout:', res, '\n')
    return 

# random bytes
vars = [random.randint(0,255) for i in range(1000)]           # must have the same number of bytes as VAR_NUM in C++
print('vars written by python:')
print(vars,'\n')

print(run_cpp(vars))
```

It creates a process calling the C++ program and writes the bytes in it's stdin via pipe. I do not immediately communicate() with the subprocess since: I want to create many of them in a loop and pass them their respective inputs. Then wait for them as they all run in parallel. (*proc.communicate()* is in this code for testing only)

When I run the code above **on Ubuntu Linux it runs as expected**: all the bytes I write from Python are printed out on stdout correctly. On Windows I get an output like the following:

```
python wrote: 1000 bytes
17(1) 27(1) 23(1) 0(1) 27(1) 23(1) 15(1) 19(1) 16(1) 27(1) 11(1) 23(1) 28(1) 13(1) 28(1) 6(1) 27(1) 28(1) 6(1) 23(1) 4(1) 13(1) 3(1) 11(1) 22(1) 14(1) 11(1) 11(1) 4(1) 4(1) 13(1) 16(1) 19(1) 21(1) 21(0) [EOF] 21(0) [EOF] 21(0) [EOF] 21(0) [EOF] 21(0) [EOF] 21(0) [EOF] 21(0) [EOF] 21(0) [EOF] 21(0) [EOF] ...
```

*proc.stdin.write(inp)* reports the correct amount of bytes written. The first few bytes are read by *read_vars()* correctly, but after a while fread seems to be reaching EOF prematurely (and the last saved byte in buf is repeatedly saved in the vars array). I tried a few different configuration options for Popen (eg shell=False), I tried flushing proc.stdin after writing it, but this behavior does not change no matter what I've tried.

This is the case if I try to write a large amount of bytes, for 10 to 200 bytes it always works correctly, for 300 to 500 it fails sometimes and for close to 1000, which is my target, it will always fail. Also the amount of bytes passed correctly always changes, some times it will read hundreds of bytes correctly without fail, sometimes it fails after the first few. To try this out, change the *#define VAR_NUM 1000* and *vars = [random.randint(0,255) for i in range(1000)]* statements in C++ and python respectivelly

I am guessing I'm missing some required python/pipe/g++ configuration, to make this work on Windows.

Edit: made the example reproducible.

Comment: This isn't a complete code example, see [mcve] It would only take a few more lines to make runnable c++ and python code with the actual data. I'd recommend reproducing with something smaller like 10 bytes. I filled in the gaps with my own guesses and it did not cause any errors, although I had to guess at things like the python string encoding. I did use newlines, as I suspected that would be the problem.

Comment: You don't need `shell=True` and its use should be avoided. You rarely want a shell as an intermediary that evaluates the command line before launching the desired program. Beyond that pipes on Unix can usually buffer at least 4KB of data. I have no idea how much data Windows pipes can buffer but based on your problem statement I would guess it is 1KB or less.

Comment: Also, as Kenny points out, your example is not a minimal reproducible example. And `chk = fread(&buf, sizeof(char), 1, stdin);` is somewhat silly since you are reading one byte at a time. There are simpler ways to read one byte at a time. Not to mention that the block of code predicated on `if(chk==0){` doesn't actually terminate the loop when an unexpected error occurs. You wrote `seems to be reaching EOF prematurely` but an EOF condition should be clear since your C++ code outputs `"[EOF] "` in that case. So why did you write "seems to be reaching EOF"?

Comment: Yes my bad, I updated the example.`if(chk==0){` does not terminate the loop since I am trying to figure out what the error is. `EOF` is unexpected since the input written by python is the same length as the `fread` loop reads (the length is known and hardcoded). Reading an EOF at any point during the loop is what I'm trying to debug.
From what I see my code fails consistently when I try to write a big number of bytes (>500b). System caused errors like this should be rare as far as my understanding goes. So there must be some way to see if it is caused by Windows buffering.

Comment: There is/was some problem with passing binary data through pipes with Windows. No idea if that is the issue, but thought I'd share.... https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=8137.0

Comment: what happens if you write the byte 26? stdin by default does not support binary data in windows. You'll have to reopen it in binary mode. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1599093/1766544

Comment: I found it by sending [i % 256 for i in range(...)] and seeing where it hit a problem. This is because you can write an actual EOF character to STDIN in the windows (if the handle is not in binary mode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by stdin not being in "Binary translation mode" on Windows, as pointed out by Mark and Kenny in the comments.

Using `freopen(NULL, "rb", stdin);` ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598985/c-read-binary-stdin/1599093#1599093)) **did not work for me**. But using `_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY)` before reading, worked perfectly (along with includes for `<fcntl.h>` and `<io.h>`, [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=msvc-170)).

Final working code for C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#define VAR_NUM 1000         // number of bytes to read
using namespace std;

void read_vars(int* vars){
    char buf;
    int chk;

    for(int i=0; i<VAR_NUM; i++){
        chk = fread(&buf, sizeof(char), 1, stdin);
        //std::cout << (int)(unsigned char)buf << "(" << chk << ") ";
        vars[i] = (int)(unsigned char)buf;
        if(chk==0){
            if(feof(stdin)){
                fwrite("[EOF error]", sizeof(char), 12, stderr);
                return;
            }
            if(ferror(stdin)){
                fwrite("[stdin ERROR]", sizeof(char), 14, stderr);
                return;
            }
            
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main(){
    if (_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY) == -1)
        fwrite("[stdin conversion ERROR]", sizeof(char), 25, stderr);
        return 1;

    int* vars = (int*) malloc(VAR_NUM*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0; i<VAR_NUM; i++) vars[i] = 0;
    read_vars(vars);
    return 0;
}
```